# Yum Repo issues

Tags: linux, centos, yum

My CentOS-Base.repo has the following mirrors:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
enabled=1

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS Server updates
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
baseurl=http://custom-url/centOS-updates/
enabled=1
```

When I say `yum install yum-utils`, it fails with the error saying

**`http://custom-url/centOS-updates/Packages/yum-utils-1.1.31-46.el7_5.noarch.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 500 - Internal Server Error
Trying other mirror.
Error downloading packages:
  yum-utils-1.1.31-46.el7_5.noarch: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.`**

I have two questions here:

- **`` Why is it looking at the `updates` repo instead of base. `yum info yum-utils` has the repo field set to `updates`. When I disable the `updates` repo in the repo file and do a `yum info yum-utils` it shows the repo field as `base` correctly. What decides the repo to look at given a package? ``**
- **`` Why is 'Package' appended to the baseUrl when it tries to find yum-utils in the updates repo? This is causing a `500 Internal Server Error` as the path with Packages appended to it is invalid ``**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why I have to do it, but cleaning the yum metadata sets the repository correctly.

I ran `yum --enablerepo=* clean all` and then retried.

Comment: Adding the link to where i got the answer from. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51711042/yum-repo-issues. Its the same question that I first posted on SO page